# Spring problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I came across this problem in physics "Physics for Scientists and Engineers
with Modern Physics by Serway"

> *A block on the end of a spring is pulled to position $x = A$ and released from rest. In one full cycle of its motion, through what total distance does it travel?*

Why the answer is $4A$ instead of $2A$?

Comment: Why the question is on hold? This is not a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the reason why you think it is $2A$ rather than $4A$ could help with a more focussed answer, but here it goes anyway.

First, note that in one period the block starts from $x=A$ and *ends* at the same position.

Second, the block does not first turn around at $x=0$, but rather at $x=-A$.

Now try breaking the motion up into two half-periods. That is, from $x=+A$ to $x=-A$ (first half), and then from $x=-A$ to $x=+A$ (second half). Try drawing a picture if you're still having trouble here.

Comment: Thanks now I see my mistake by saying "First, note that in one period the block starts from x=A and ends at the same position."